# How to show edges of a cube in OpenGL on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have drawn cubes using OpenGL. Now, I have to show only the edges of that cube. It should look like a cube cage. How can I do this?

My code look likes as follows:

// Each element is a triangle strip of 16 vertices.

```
            vertices.put(x).put(y).put(zz);
            vertices.put(x).put(y).put(zz);
            vertices.put(xx).put(y).put(zz);
            vertices.put(x).put(yy).put(zz);
            vertices.put(xx).put(yy).put(zz);
            vertices.put(xx).put(yy).put(z);
            vertices.put(xx).put(y).put(zz);
            vertices.put(xx).put(y).put(z);
            vertices.put(x).put(y).put(z);
            vertices.put(xx).put(yy).put(z);
            vertices.put(x).put(yy).put(z);
            vertices.put(x).put(yy).put(zz);
            vertices.put(x).put(y).put(z);
            vertices.put(x).put(y).put(zz);
            vertices.put(xx).put(y).put(zz);
            vertices.put(xx).put(y).put(zz);

            int color = Color.GRAY; 
            for ( int j = 0; j < 16; ++j ) 
            {
                colors.put(color);
            }  
                   vertices.position(0);
                   colors.position(0);
```

Comment: How do you draw the cube? Show some code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060987/android-how-do-i-draw-a-wireframe-over-object-in-opengl-2-0

Comment: I'm really confused with it.If possible can I please get simple example to show edges of a cube. Please check above question where I uploaded my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to draw the lines defining the edges of the cube with the `GL_LINES` primitive.

Comment: If possible can you provide a example. See above code in a question.